# Gstreamer udpsrc fails on Android

Tags: java, android, c, video-streaming, gstreamer

I'm attempting to open an rtp stream sent over udp and encoded as h.264 with gstreamer android. I am able to open said stream on my laptop using gst-launch-1.0 with the following gstreamer pipeline string:

```
"gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=4711 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink"
```

I've modified gstreamer android example tutorial-5.c to use the same pipeline string when creating the relevant gstreamer pipeline element. Specifically, I've changed the line in app_function (void *userdata) that originally called a playbin element to interpret a URI string to the following :

```
  data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch("udpsrc port=4711 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink", &error);
```

However, when I run the application in emulator on a device, it crashes. Here is the logcat output:

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (15744) for package org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_5 ----------------------------
2023-08-04 14:03:22.115 15744-15744 GStreamer+...tivedemux2 org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  0:00:00.008497396 0x76a8551380 ../ext/adaptivedemux2/gstadaptivedemuxelement.c:41:adaptivedemux2_base_element_init Failed to load libsoup library
2023-08-04 14:03:22.116 15744-15744 GStreamer+...tivedemux2 org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  0:00:00.009767969 0x76a8551380 ../ext/adaptivedemux2/gstadaptivedemuxelement.c:41:adaptivedemux2_base_element_init Failed to load libsoup library
2023-08-04 14:03:22.117 15744-15744 GStreamer+...tivedemux2 org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  0:00:00.010928594 0x76a8551380 ../ext/adaptivedemux2/gstadaptivedemuxelement.c:41:adaptivedemux2_base_element_init Failed to load libsoup library
2023-08-04 14:03:22.133 15744-15744 VideoCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime image/vnd.android.heic
2023-08-04 14:03:22.141 15744-15744 AudioCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime audio/x-ima
2023-08-04 14:03:22.141 15744-15744 AudioCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime audio/x-ape
2023-08-04 14:03:22.142 15744-15744 AudioCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime audio/evrc
2023-08-04 14:03:22.142 15744-15744 AudioCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1
2023-08-04 14:03:22.143 15744-15744 AudioCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2
2023-08-04 14:03:22.143 15744-15744 AudioCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
2023-08-04 14:03:22.143 15744-15744 AudioCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma
2023-08-04 14:03:22.143 15744-15744 AudioCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime audio/evrc
2023-08-04 14:03:22.143 15744-15744 AudioCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime audio/qcelp
2023-08-04 14:03:22.156 15744-15744 VideoCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime video/mp43
2023-08-04 14:03:22.157 15744-15744 VideoCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unrecognized profile/level 1/32 for video/mp4v-es
2023-08-04 14:03:22.157 15744-15744 VideoCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
2023-08-04 14:03:22.157 15744-15744 VideoCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unrecognized profile/level 32768/64 for video/mp4v-es
2023-08-04 14:03:22.157 15744-15744 VideoCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime video/wvc1
2023-08-04 14:03:22.158 15744-15744 VideoCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv7
2023-08-04 14:03:22.158 15744-15744 VideoCapabilities       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv8
2023-08-04 14:03:22.158 15744-15744 GStreamer+amc           org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  E  0:00:00.052010521 0x76a8551380 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamc.c:551:accepted_color_formats Unknown color format 0x7fa30c06, ignoring
2023-08-04 14:03:22.158 15744-15744 GStreamer+amc           org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  E  0:00:00.052055625 0x76a8551380 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamc.c:551:accepted_color_formats Unknown color format 0x6, ignoring
2023-08-04 14:03:22.158 15744-15744 GStreamer+amc           org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  0:00:00.052066354 0x76a8551380 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamc.c:311:scan_codecs video/avc decoder has unknown color formats, only direct rendering will be supported
2023-08-04 14:03:22.158 15744-15744 GStreamer+amc           org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  E  0:00:00.052139375 0x76a8551380 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamc.c:551:accepted_color_formats Unknown color format 0x7fa30c06, ignoring
... repeats ...
202023-08-04 14:03:22.166 15744-15744 GStreamer+amc           org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  0:00:00.059945104 0x76a8551380 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamc.c:2421:gst_amc_codec_info_to_caps Unsupported mimetype 'video/x-ms-wmv7'
2023-08-04 14:03:22.166 15744-15744 GStreamer+amc           org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  0:00:00.059977240 0x76a8551380 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamc.c:2421:gst_amc_codec_info_to_caps Unsupported mimetype 'video/x-ms-wmv8'
2023-08-04 14:03:22.168 15744-15744 GLib+GLib               org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  GError set over the top of a previous GError or uninitialized memory.
                                                                                                    This indicates a bug in someone's code. You must ensure an error is NULL before it's set.
                                                                                                    The overwriting error message was: Failed to get static field ID EFFECT_SKETCH (Ljava/lang/String;): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/String;" field "EFFECT_SKETCH" in class "Landroid/hardware/Camera$Parameters;" or its superclasses
                                                                                                    java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/String;" field "EFFECT_SKETCH" in class "Landroid/hardware/Camera$Parameters;" or its superclasses
                                                                                                        at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GStreamer.nativeInit(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GStreamer.init(GStreamer.java:24)
                                                                                                        at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_5.Tutorial5.onCreate(Tutorial5.java:64)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7957)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7946)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(Activity
2023-08-04 14:03:22.169 15744-15744 GLib+GLib-GObject       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  E  Object class GstAHCSrc doesn't implement property 'exposure-mode' from interface 'GstPhotography'
2023-08-04 14:03:22.194 15744-15744 GStreamer               org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  GStreamer initialization complete
2023-08-04 14:03:22.198 15744-15744 MultiWindowDecorSupport org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  updateCaptionType >> DecorView@2267800[], isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false, hasWindowControllerCallback: true
2023-08-04 14:03:22.198 15744-15744 MultiWindowDecorSupport org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@2267800[]
2023-08-04 14:03:22.226 15744-15744 GStreamer               org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  Activity created with no saved state:
2023-08-04 14:03:22.226 15744-15744 GStreamer               org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I    playing:false position:0 duration: 0 uri: rtsp://192.168.1.20:8554/test
2023-08-04 14:03:22.226 15744-15744 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.120206667 0x76a8551380 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:483:gst_native_init Created CustomData at 0x7648beafe0
2023-08-04 14:03:22.227 15744-15744 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.120244948 0x76a8551380 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:485:gst_native_init Created GlobalRef for app object at 0x3f36
2023-08-04 14:03:22.227 15744-15793 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.120363594 0x7648b92460 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:396:app_function Creating pipeline in CustomData at 0x7648beafe0
2023-08-04 14:03:22.228 15744-15793 GLib+GLib-GObject       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  g_object_get_is_valid_property: object class 'GstPipeline' has no property named 'flags'
2023-08-04 14:03:22.228 15744-15793 GLib+GLib-GObject       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  g_object_set_is_valid_property: object class 'GstPipeline' has no property named 'flags'
2023-08-04 14:03:22.232 15744-15795 AdrenoGLES-0            org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  QUALCOMM build                   : f141d58, If15e50a99e
                                                                                                    Build Date                       : 06/10/20
                                                                                                    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.29.00.08
                                                                                                    Local Branch                     : 
                                                                                                    Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.UM.8.12.C1.10.00.00.649.113
                                                                                                    Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                                                    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2023-08-04 14:03:22.232 15744-15795 AdrenoGLES-0            org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  Build Config                     : S P 8.0.12 AArch64
2023-08-04 14:03:22.232 15744-15795 AdrenoGLES-0            org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
2023-08-04 14:03:22.232 15744-15782 NativeCust...ncyManager org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::BpCustomFrequencyManager()
2023-08-04 14:03:22.235 15744-15795 AdrenoGLES-0            org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  PFP: 0x016dd087, ME: 0x00000000
2023-08-04 14:03:22.236 15744-15744 ViewRootIm...Tutorial5] org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  setView = com.android.internal.policy.DecorView@2267800 TM=true MM=false
2023-08-04 14:03:22.240 15744-15744 SurfaceView             org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  onWindowVisibilityChanged(0) true org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_5.GStreamerSurfaceView{b5f9fb4 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f07007d app:id/surface_video} of ViewRootImpl@b3568ab[Tutorial5]
2023-08-04 14:03:22.240 15744-15795 GStreamer+glcontext     org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  0:00:00.133592292 0x7648b59f00 ../gst-libs/gst/gl/egl/gstglcontext_egl.c:553:gst_gl_context_egl_dump_config:<glcontextegl0> unknown EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE value 3300
... repeats ..
2023-08-04 14:03:22.243 15744-15744 GStreamer               org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  onMeasure called with 320x240
2023-08-04 14:03:22.245 15744-15798 GStreamer+glcontext     org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  0:00:00.138893750 0x76a489a240 ../gst-libs/gst/gl/egl/gstglcontext_egl.c:553:gst_gl_context_egl_dump_config:<glcontextegl1> unknown EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE value 3300
... repeats ...
2023-08-04 14:03:22.248 15744-15744 ViewRootIm...Tutorial5] org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=4 res=0x7 s={true 508010508288} ch=true
2023-08-04 14:03:22.248 15744-15782 OpenGLRenderer          org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  createReliableSurface : 0x773ff9e240(0x7647c93000)
2023-08-04 14:03:22.249 15744-15793 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.142321250 0x7648b92460 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:450:app_function Entering main loop... (CustomData:0x7648beafe0)
2023-08-04 14:03:22.249 15744-15793 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.142345729 0x7648b92460 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:75:attach_current_thread Attaching thread 0x7648b92460
2023-08-04 14:03:22.249 15744-15793 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.142797604 0x7648b92460 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:115:set_ui_message Setting message to: State changed to READY
2023-08-04 14:03:22.249 15744-15782 OpenGLRenderer          org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x0 -> 0x0
2023-08-04 14:03:22.250 15744-15744 GStreamer               org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  onMeasure called with 320x240
2023-08-04 14:03:22.253 15744-15744 SurfaceView             org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  surfaceCreated 1 #8 org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_5.GStreamerSurfaceView{b5f9fb4 V.E...... ......ID 0,964-1080,1774 #7f07007d app:id/surface_video}
2023-08-04 14:03:22.253 15744-15744 GStreamer               org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  Surface created: Surface(name=null)/@0x5c81638
2023-08-04 14:03:22.253 15744-15744 SurfaceView             org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  surfaceChanged (1080,810) 1 #8 org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_5.GStreamerSurfaceView{b5f9fb4 V.E...... ......ID 0,964-1080,1774 #7f07007d app:id/surface_video}
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GStreamer               org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  Surface changed to format 4 width 1080 height 810
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.147286094 0x76a8551380 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:621:gst_native_surface_init Received surface 0x7fc630eb28 (native window 0x7647ce3010)
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.147315417 0x76a8551380 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:75:attach_current_thread Attaching thread 0x76a8551380
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.147326510 0x76a8551380 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:369:check_initialization_complete Initialization complete, notifying application. native_window:0x7647ce3010 main_loop:0x76ac99c150
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GLib+GLib-GObject       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  invalid cast from 'GstPipeline' to 'GstVideoOverlay'
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GLib+GStreamer-Video    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  E  gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle: assertion 'GST_IS_VIDEO_OVERLAY (overlay)' failed
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GStreamer               org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  GStreamer initialized:
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GStreamer               org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I    playing:false position:0 uri: rtsp://192.168.1.20:8554/test
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.147399167 0x76a8551380 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:529:gst_native_set_uri Setting URI to rtsp://192.168.1.20:8554/test
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GLib+GLib-GObject       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  g_object_set_is_valid_property: object class 'GstPipeline' has no property named 'uri'
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.147559115 0x76a8551380 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:580:gst_native_set_position Scheduling seek to 0:00:00.000000000 for later
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15744 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.147580417 0x76a8551380 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:561:gst_native_pause Setting state to PAUSED
2023-08-04 14:03:22.254 15744-15793 GStreamer+tutorial-5    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  0:00:00.148201146 0x7648b92460 C:/software/gstreamer-1.22/subprojects/gst-docs/examples/tutorials/android/android-tutorial-5/jni/tutorial-5.c:115:set_ui_message Setting message to: State changed to PAUSED
2023-08-04 14:03:22.255 15744-15793 GLib+GLib-GObject       org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  g_object_get_is_valid_property: object class 'GstPipeline' has no property named 'video-sink'
2023-08-04 14:03:22.255 15744-15793 ials.tutorial_          org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  W  0xebadde09 skipped times: 0
2023-08-04 14:03:22.255 15744-15793 libc                    org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x773b7f9c54 in tid 15793 (Thread-8), pid 15744 (ials.tutorial_5)
2023-08-04 14:03:22.265 15744-15782 OpenGLRenderer          org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  makeCurrent EglSurface : 0x0 -> 0x763fc26600
2023-08-04 14:03:22.331 15744-15782 NativeCust...ncyManager org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  E  [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::sendDrawingTid()
2023-08-04 14:03:22.331 15744-15782 OpenGLRenderer          org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  GPIS:: SetUp Pid : 15744    Tid : 15782
2023-08-04 14:03:22.341 15744-15744 ViewRootIm...Tutorial5] org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=3 res=0x1 s={true 508010508288} ch=false
2023-08-04 14:03:22.343 15744-15744 ViewRootIm...Tutorial5] org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
2023-08-04 14:03:22.344 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@2267800[Tutorial5]
2023-08-04 14:03:22.344 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2023-08-04 14:03:22.348 15744-15744 EmergencyMode           org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  [EmergencyManager] android createPackageContext successful
2023-08-04 14:03:22.351 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@2267800[Tutorial5]
2023-08-04 14:03:22.351 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2023-08-04 14:03:22.351 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  V  Starting input: tba=org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_5 ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2023-08-04 14:03:22.351 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  startInputInner - Id : 0
2023-08-04 14:03:22.351 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  I  startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2023-08-04 14:03:22.354 15744-15744 ViewRootIm...Tutorial5] org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  MSG_RESIZED: frame=(0,0,1080,2400) ci=(0,78,0,144) vi=(0,78,0,144) or=1
2023-08-04 14:03:22.354 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@2267800[Tutorial5]
2023-08-04 14:03:22.354 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  getNavigationBarColor() -855310
2023-08-04 14:03:22.354 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  V  Starting input: tba=org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_5 ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
2023-08-04 14:03:22.354 15744-15744 InputMethodManager      org...streamer.tutorials.tutorial_5  D  startInputInner - Id : 0
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (15744) for package org.freedesktop.gstreamer.tutorials.tutorial_5 ----------------------------
```

For background, I've been able to open rtsp streams and other example video sources on the device just fine with gstreamer for android. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.